# using asp.net core(Repository, unit of work) with xamarin forms in the same solution

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, repository, dto, unit-of-work

I'm creating an asp.net core web app which will contain an API also, 
I want to use unit of work and repository pattern using entity framework core then expose the API using DTO objects and not direct entities, to benefit of code re usability i added my client xamarin forms project to the same solution which will only reference the DTO Project. 
So my solution now contains the following projects:
DAL
Repository (References DAL)
DTO
WebApp (Asp.net core) (References Repository and DAL)
Xamarin(PCL)(References DTO)
My problem is project types are not compatible, actually i do not know if this is the right way to do this, i need some hints on creating (web app with API) with xamarin client that can consume the web API with the right approach .
Shall i use pcl, normal class library, .net core or .netstandard ?

Comment: I didn't quite like the idea of messing so different projects on the same solution.. but this is just my personal preference. Regarding the DTO returning part.. you are more talking about having a "contract" between your API and it`s clients. What you could do is creating just a normal class library with the models and then referencing it on both projects. Just a netstandard plain class library.

Comment: Another option, you could create some sort of  APIClient, that would wrap your API methods and types. Think on this like using the SDK for communicating with Google APIs for instance.

Comment: @jpgrassi I am using asp.net core so a normal class library can't be referenced. using a .netstandard works but the project won't build giving strange compatibility errors. also a normal class library is not compatible with xamarin forms. actually i can handle the server side making all other projects of type .net core. but remains the DTO. I understand what you by an API Client but would it save me from rewriting the contract on the client side ? is there any other way I am not aware of ?

Comment: First: strange compatibility errors: You have to check and fix this. You should be able to add a netstandard class library on both projects. Second: Yes it would. The wraper client for your API would site along with your DTO's on the class library. You could then, provide this api client as a nugget package. Any application (your xamarin for instance) can just intall-package and be ready to go. The api client is just a suggestion.. the main point is that you can separate your DTO's and add them as you need. Either via project reference.. or a nugget package, for instance.

Comment: @jpgrassi  i think the problem is with visual studio 2015, i'm upgrading to 2017, as for the nuget package i've never created one before but i created class libraries etc... Maybe it is different type of project with different deployment, i will check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded to visual studio 2017, and now all project templates are available, and now i can reference projects with no problems.

i recommend that every developer use vs 2017 for .net core since the support in vs 2015 is limited especially for generating model classes from existing database in ef.net core